# Change Time zone without change the date format

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I have **date format** like `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"`, and the date is

```
String date = "Tue, 14 Aug 2012 07:26:33 +0000";
```

How to change to `+0700` time zone without change the date format?

This is what I try

```
String sDate = null;
Date date = null;
try {
    sDate = "Tue, 14 Aug 2012 07:26:33 +0000";
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    try {
        date = curFormater.parse(sDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (DropboxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
lastUpdate.setText("Last Update : " + date.toString());
```

but the result is **`Tue Aug 14 14:26:33 ICT 2012`**

Comment: Parse the date, and then output it in that format

Comment: @therefromhere I mean change the time zone

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean - parse the date, change the timezone and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there, you've parsed the date correctly, but you're relying on the default `toString()` instead of the format you've already created.

Try this instead for the last line:

```
lastUpdate.setText(curFormater.format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, `curFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());`, after I set the timezone to default, it works

Comment: Ah yeah I was looking at the formatting rather than the TZ stuff.  So that will output in whatever TZ your environment is set up to use.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to add a manual number of hours, you could do it something like this:

```
static final Long oneHourInMilliseconds = new Long(3600000);
static final DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

public static Long addHours(Date time, int hours)
{
    return time.getTime() + (hours * oneHourInMilliseconds);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    String dateAsString = "Tue, 14 Aug 2012 07:26:33 +0000";
    Date before = d.parse(dateAsString);
    Date after = new Date(addHours(before, 7));
    System.out.println("Before: " + before + ". After: " + after);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

date -d works in Unix for this.